# Get x value of highstock navigator handle when mouseup occurs

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I searched through the API to find if there was a way to get the handle x-values after a mouseup event but I couldn't find anything. The only thing I could find was how to get the values for the main series, nothing for the navigator itself. Does anybody know of a way to get these values? Here's some sample code I'm using at the moment which has a navigator slider at the bottom for you to mess around with. I want to drag a handle from the navigator and once I release it pop up an alert message with the x value.

http://jsfiddle.net/fqptH/2/

```
var highPoint=0;
var highCount=0;

$(function() {   
function getPoints() {
    var dataPoints = [];
    for (var i=0; i<=100; i++) {
        if (i == highPoint && highCount < 20) {
            dataPoints[i]=[i,8];
            highCount++;
        } else {
            var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            dataPoints[i]=[i,randomnumber];
        }
        if (highCount == 20) { highCount = 0; }
    }
    if (highPoint == 100) { highPoint=0; }
    if (highCount == 19) { highPoint++; }
    return dataPoints;
} 

var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    navigator : {
        series: {
            //data: [[1,1],[2,2],[3,1]]
            data: getPoints()
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [[1,1],[2,2],[3,1]]
        //data: getPoints()      
    }]
});

function update() {
    //chart.series[0].setData(getPoints());
    setTimeout(update, 100);        
}
update();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this after the plot is drawn:

```
// left handle
$(Highcharts.charts[0].scroller.handles[0].element).mouseup(function(){
    var minPixel = Highcharts.charts[0].scroller.zoomedMin;
    alert(Highcharts.charts[0].scroller.xAxis.toValue(minPixel));
});

// right handle
$(Highcharts.charts[0].scroller.handles[1].element).mouseup(function(){
    var maxPixel = Highcharts.charts[0].scroller.zoomedMax;
    alert(Highcharts.charts[0].scroller.xAxis.toValue(maxPixel));
});
```

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zG68V/1/).

Comment: Nice. Much better than my answer. I didn't know you could access the handles that way.

Comment: Thanks Mark, there's a limitation with this though that if your cursor moves off the handle it doesn't output the values and I would also like to output the values if the scrollbar is moved. I have some code now that somewhat does that but for some reason it likes to reset itself a lot when moving the handle with updated data. Do you know why this code is doing that? Just move the handles around and you'll see what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/fqptH/7/

Comment: @BradSmith, you are updating the navigator every 100ms; why?  This is interfering with your moving the navigator, by the time you've moved it, it's been queued to redraw many times over.

Comment: I'm updating it because the app I want to use this for will have its data updated just like this. The data right now is just a simulation of course but in the actual app it will be spectrum data for RF.

Comment: I think I have it working about as good as I'm going to be able to get it to work. The only thing I wish I would be able to do is to make the main chart and navigator independent of each other. I don't want the navigator setting the thresholds of the chart. I want to manually do that myself with the values I'm capturing from the navigator. http://jsfiddle.net/fqptH/8/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much help this is but it might get you on your way: http://jsfiddle.net/fqptH/3/

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
            console.log('<b>Set extremes:</b> e.min: '+ e.min +
                ' | e.max: '+ e.max + ' | e.trigger: ' + e.trigger);
        }
    }
},
```

It seems to trigger repeatedly as you move the handle so I'm not sure how you will know when it is done and then trigger your pop up.

Comment: Worked for me. Seems like afterSetExtremes event might be better.

Answer (score 0):

With the helpful tips from @Mark I came up with the following. toValue doesn't resolve the numbers correctly but looking through the source you can do something very similar with .translate(value, true). This will translate a pixel position to an axis value.

```
var scroller = Highcharts.charts[0].scroller;
var navMin = scroller.xAxis.translate(scroller.zoomedMin, true);
var navMax = scroller.xAxis.translate(scroller.zoomedMax, true);
alert('min: '+Math.round(navMin)+"\nmax: "+Math.round(navMax));
```

Here's a full jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fqptH/9/